# Disable debug configuration saving in Eclipse / XDebug

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging, xdebug

I have a large `Yii` based web app, that I try to debug with XDebug. I add a breakpoint to an ActiveRecord model file that's included almost everywhere.

So when I try to debug `models/User.php`, I add a breakpoint, start debugging, it asks me for URL to debug, I point it to `http://localhost/users/search` and saves my `User.php` debug configuration to that endpoint.

But if next time I want to debug same file under `http://localhost/profile/create`, I'd have to go to `PHP Web Application` configurations, delete the `User` entry and then re-enter the URL.

This is quite annoying and tedious. Is there a way to NOT save configuration per file by default? Is there a good tutorial how would you debug large application where you have lot's of inclusions and more complicated routing (such that endpoints are not actual files)?